# Prevent Empty xmlns - ReplaceWith() Linq

Tags: .net, xml, linq

What I'm doing is I have 2 templates of XML that I use to quickly create a XML document. I first replace data in template #2, which will then be used to replace an element from template #1. I can successfully replace, however the node I inserted into template #1 has a lingering emtpy xmlns.

For example:

Template1

```
<root xmlns="namespace">
  <Replace/>
</root>
```

Template2

```
<Replace>
  <child/>
</Replace>
```

My final output is:

```
<root xmlns="namespace">
 <Replace xmlns="">
  <child/>
 </Replace>
</root>
```

If I include the same namespace in template #2, I end up with this:

```
<root xmlns="namespace">
 <Replace xmlns="namespace">
  <child/>
 </Replace>
</root>
```

Here's my code:

```
Imports <xmlns:ns="namespace">

Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Template1.xml")
Dim replaceDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Template2.xml")

Dim x = From elem As XElement In xDoc.<ns:root>.<ns:Replace>.First
x.ReplaceWith(replaceDoc.Elements)

xDoc.Save("Final.xml")
```

I would like only the root element to contain the namespace. Any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: I suspect that this is because you're thinking of XML as just text. It's not. The namespaces are an important part of the information that XML contains. If `Replace` didn't have the `xmlns=""`, that would imply that it's the `Replace` element from the `namespace` namespace, and not any other `Replace` element from any other namespace. If that's so, why isn't it in that namespace already in template 2?

Comment: I tried including the same namespace in template #2, since ultimately it will have the same namespace as template #1. However when I do that both the <root> and <Replace> elements have the namespace.

Comment: In that case, it shouldn't matter. From an informational perspective, `<Element1 xmlns="urn:namespace1"><Element2/></Element1>` and `<Element1 xmlns="urn:namespace1"><Element2 xmlns="urn:namespace1"/></Element1>` contain *exactly* the same information.

Comment: I agree, but I would still like to see if it's doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go with your second variant (where you do want `Replace` to be in `namespace` and have that in the template) then the final line should just be:

```
xDoc.Save("Final.xml",SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces)
```

[`SaveOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: HIGH FIVE!!! That did exactly what I was looking for, and so simple too. When I get more rep, I'll come back and check this answer.